# Question about different gametes that can be produced

Tags: genetics, homework

I have a question from a past exam that asks the following:

*"For the organism of genotype AABbCcDDEe (homozygous for 2 genes, heterozygous for 3 genes), how many different types of gametes will be made if the C gene and the E gene are linked on the same chromosome while the remaining genes are all on different chromosomes?"*

However, I have no answer key, and these answers are the choices:

A. 2

B. 3

C. 4

D. 8

E. 9

Here's my approach to the question:

We have 5 traits, and each trait consists of 2 alleles. To make functional gametes, each gamete must receive one of each allele so that it can survive. Clearly, for AA and DD, there's only one choice: A, and D.

However, for Bb, Cc, and Ee, things are a little different.

C and E are linked on the same chromosome. c and e are on different chromosomes. Therefore, a gamete can have either CE, or c and e. Similarly, a gamete can have either B or b.

Therefore, shouldn't we be able to create 4 different types of gametes?:

ABCDE, ABcDe, AbCDE, AbcDe

So wouldn't the answer be C. 4?

Please show me any mistakes I might be making, or any gaps in my understanding. This would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are correct**

Assuming that by `linked`, the question assumes perfect linkage (no cross-over ever happen), then your answer is correct! Good job!

**Comments**

Here are a few comments though...

> We have 5 traits, and each trait consists of 2 alleles.

There are 5 loci. A locus does not necessarily match to a single trait and a single trait does not necessarily match to a single locus. Actually, it is very very rarely (if ever) the case.

> To make functional gametes, each gamete must receive one of each allele so that it can survive.

This is not necessarily true. A "normal meiosis" (not leading to variation in copy number) may create a non-viable genotype and a "abnormal meiosis" (leading to variation in copy number) may create a viable genotype. But, it is true that we will only assume "normal meiosis" for this answer.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for answering my question and giving additional advice. Sorry that I couldn't get around to accepting your answer and giving feedback straight away. Your answer helped put these concepts I learned into greater context since it seemed like I had a kind of naive understanding of meiosis.